# How to use depth value from /camera/depth/image?

Tags: opencv, openni, turtlebot, sensor-msgs, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [this code](https://github.com/strands-project/vision/blob/master/src/show_depth.cpp)

```
topic is: /camera/depth/image
type: /sensor_msgs/Image
```

According to the code, `(msg->data[0])` is providing the value of Top-Left Corner.

I wanted to ask:

1. How can I get the value of the Top-Right Corner, Centre, etc.
2. How can I get the normal depth value that can tell me the distance from the object? Do I need to do some mathematical work or is there a method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125241/how-to-use-depth-value-from-/camera/depth/image?/) by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-24**:
Your reference code helped, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the code the message is already converted to a cv::Mat ( cv_ptr->image ). Use this Matrix if you want to do some processing of the data.

E.g. you can use

```
float dist_val = cv_ptr->image.at<float>( 10, 10 );
```

to get the value at 10, 10. (There are much faster methods if you not just want to access one pixel, though).

See, http://docs.opencv.org for infos on how to handle your data with OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on 2014-02-10**:
Thanks for your help.
I visited the link you gave. Please guide me which topics/tutorials should I follow?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-02-10**:
That very much depends on what you actually want to do. Probably some of the core and improc tutorials. If you want to do object detection: "Creating Bounding boxes and circles for contours"(particularly cv::findContours() usage). Threshold works also for dist imgs. Likely you need some normalizing.

**Comment by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on 2014-02-17**:
Thanks for your reply.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-24**:
Thanks, @Wolf, this solution worked for me. I have used `/camera/depth/image_raw` as an input rostopic.

My answer with complete code (c++): https://answers.ros.org/question/141741/calculate-depth-from-point-cloud-xyz/?answer=381085#post-id-381085

Extra:

- To get image dimension: `std::cout << "Image dimension (Row x Col): " << cv_ptr->image.rows << " x " << cv_ptr->image.cols << endl;`
- To get
  image global max and min depth
  values:

````
double max = 0.0;
cv::minMaxLoc(cv_ptr->image, &min, &max, 0, 0);
std::cout << "Min value: " << min << " " << "Max value: " << max << endl;```
````